# How To Automatically Set ALL Note Velocity for MIDI Files in FL Studio?

Tags: midi, home-studio, volume, fl-studio, sound-editing

i am new in sound design and home audio production, right now i am playing with FL Studio.

I know i can change note velocity for imported Midi files in FL Studio, one note by one note. But, how i can automatically set velocity for ALL note in that channel? Because i want velocity for that channel to be flat (same from start to end)

Thanks for your answer

Comment: I think you ought to read the user manual. This is not a sound design question. This is a "how do I operate my software?" question, easily answerable by the manufacturer or their documentation.

Comment: My apologies, i am quite new in this field, even i dont know what the difference between sound design and sound software question. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Check out the Level Scale Tool in FL-Studio. This might help.

Comment: Thank you @Mark, very appreciate your help!